# Using array variable within loop for two variables awk

Tags: loops, variables, awk

I have an array with few variables for a loop, I want `awk` to check against one variable, and another persistent string.

my script looks like this:

```
wget https://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/release-109/gtf/homo_sapiens/Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf.gz
gunzip Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf.gz

declare -a arr=("gene" "exon" "transcript" "three_prime_utr" "five_prime_utr")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   tail -n +6 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | awk '{ if ($3==$i && $7="+") {print $0}}' > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.$i.gtf
   head -n5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | cat - Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.$i.gtf > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.$i.gtf. 
   mv Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.$i.gtf. Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.$i.gtf
 done

rm Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf
```

the results is as follows:

```
$ wc -l *.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.five_prime_utr.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gene.gtf
   3420366 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.three_prime_utr.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.transcript.gtf
```

Meaning I am unable to use `$i` properly.

If I run one script individually e.g. using `exon`

```
   tail -n +6 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | awk '{ if ($3=="exon" &&$7="+") {print $0}}' > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf
   head -n5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | cat - Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf. 
   mv Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf. Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf
```

I get

```
   1648283 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.five_prime_utr.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gene.gtf
   3420366 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.three_prime_utr.gtf
         5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.transcript.gtf
```

The original Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf file
[image: Original Data with column 3 and 7 columns of interest]

The Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.exon.gtf file
[image: Exon filtered gtf file]

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do in the **big picture**?

Comment: There's Perl's modules out there for parsing `gtf` files: https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::FeatureIO::gtf  and  https://metacpan.org/pod/GenOO::GeneCollection::Factory::GTF

Comment: sadly these modules are not useful to me, as I am trying to filter for specific variables.

Comment: Best I can tell you should be doing all of that in 1 call to awk, not calling awk in a shell loop but without a [mcve] with concise, testable **textual** (no images and no links) sample input and expected output in your question there isn't much we could do to help you. So we can help you - please [edit] your question to clearly state what you're trying to do and provide minimal, complete sample input and expected output that demonstrates your needs and we could copy/paste to test a potential solution with,

Comment: You may be interested in [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) but fixing THAT problem with `$i` in your awk script is not the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: the last comment did it.

Comment: I was afraid of that. You're taking the band-aid instead of letting us help you set the broken leg. Oh well, you can always ask a new question if you'd like to make your script vastly more efficient and robust. At least copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about though to patch some of the holes.

Comment: Did the shellcheck, how would I be able to improve on the code?

Comment: See [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743745/using-array-variable-within-loop-for-two-variables-awk#comment133617638_75743745) for how you'd need to improve your question so we could help you.

Comment: You should just accept your own answer to this one though (or not) and ask a new question if you want to do that as it'd require a big change to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here the is the correct code -

```
declare -a arr=("gene" "exon" "transcript" "three_prime_utr" "five_prime_utr")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
   tail -n +6 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | awk -v var="$i" '{ if ($3==var && $7="+") {print $0}}' > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf
   head -n5 Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf | cat - Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf > Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf. 
   mv Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf. Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf
   convert2bed --max-mem=40G -i gtf < Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf. >  Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109."$i".gtf.bed
 done

rm Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.109.gtf
```

Comment: Mainly just be aware that if anything fails in your script you'll ignore that and continue processing thereby producing bad output and you'll destroy your input file. Look into how to test exit status (e.g. with `&&`) before using output and/or moving, removing, or overwriting any input files.